# Как в SQL проставить определенное количество цифр после запятой?

Tags: sql, oracle

Для значений нужно 3 знака после запятой, а для процентов 2 знака и они должны присутствовать всегда.

Я видел прием с to_char, но у меня могут быть значения разной длины, поэтому этот метод не слишком предпочтителен для меня. Поэтому интересует есть ли простой способ всегда отображать 2-3 цифры после запятой?

round(val, 2) - не работает и выдает следующие результаты:

```
51708.58
50482.2
```

Comment: CAST to DECIMAL(n, m)

Comment: В смысле, вам нужно обязательно с нулями на конце? Это задача для GUI-клиента. А в БД числа должны оставаться числами.

Comment: Да, обязательно с нулями на конце. В GUI-клиенте это чрезвычайно сложно.

Comment: @cpp_user, не сработало.

Comment: Где не сработало? На клиенте или на сервере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> round(val, 2) - не работает и выдает следующие результаты

`round(val, 2)` работает так, как и должен, он округляет число до двух знаков после запятой. Другое дело, что вы видите то, что отображает ваш клиент (так как формат отображения данных не может храниться внутри данных, клиент всё равно будет преобразовывать значение в тот вид, под который он настроен).

Если нет возможности задать маску отображения для числовых значений на клиенте, то вам остается только преобразовывать данные в строку с помощью `to_char`.

```
with t as
   (select 123.3 as num from dual union all
    select 123 as num from dual union all
    select 123.35 as num from dual union all
    select 0.3 as num from dual union all
    select 0.35 as num from dual union all
    select 123.35050 as num from dual union all
    select 1 as num from dual union all
    select -123.3 as num from dual)
select trim(to_char(num, '999999999999999999990.99')) as val
from t
```